# Plugin vue with tailwindcss library not compiled from project

Tags: vue.js, package, tailwind-css

Private package : vue 2.6, rollup 2.60, tailwind postcss7-compat@^2.2.17
Project : Laravel 8, vue 2.6, webpack mix 6.0, vuetify

I'm creating Vue private package with tailwindcss library.

My package standalone is working :
[image: standalone package]

But, when I want include this package from my (laravel) project :

[image: package from project]

Tailwind CSS is not compiled.

I don't know if it's package or project has problem. Ask me and I give more information.